# Django admin site get id to show in html

Tags: django

I just want that if the admin select the students, it will get the id and show in the html template

admin.py

```
@admin.register(studentDiscount)
class studentDiscount(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('Students_Enrollment_Records', 'Discount_Type','my_url_field')
    ordering = ('Students_Enrollment_Records',)
    search_fields = ('Students_Enrollment_Records',)
    def my_url_field(self, obj):
        return format_html("<a href='https://www.school.ph/enrollmentform/?StudentID=pk'>Report</a>", obj.Discount_Type)
    my_url_field.allow_tags = False
    my_url_field.short_description = 'Report'
```

this is my models.py

```
class studentDiscount(models.Model):
    Students_Enrollment_Records = models.ForeignKey(StudentsEnrollmentRecord, related_name='+',
                                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Discount_Type = models.ForeignKey(Discount, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want for use `Discount_Type.pk` in the URL use format like this:

`return format_html("https://www.school.ph/enrollmentform/?StudentID={}'>Report", obj.Discount_Type.pk)`